# Integer Stack program

Tags: c, integer, stack

can someone pls give me the program for this 
Integer Stack

Implement a stack of integers using arrays.

It is assumed that the stack has a maximum size of 50 elements. Any attempt to increase this size results in an error printed on the screen, however the program does not terminate. Similarly the POP operations print an error, however the program does not terminate. Using this stack simulate a continuous inflow of commands.

Input description: The first input is a single number N denoting the number of test cases. The next input, in a new line, is P denoting the number of commands given. Then there are exactly P lines, each denoting a command. There are 3 types of commands:

PUSH a POP TOP

Push command is necessarily followed by a single integer (a) with a space between the push and the integer. POP and TOP have no following integers.

Output: For each test case print exactly P lines. After every PUSH operation print either the integer pushed in or the error "STACK OVERFLOW".
After every POP operation print either the integer popped out or the error "STACK UNDERFLOW". After every TOP command print the top element of the stack or the error "STACK UNDERFLOW".

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 50
int ar[MAX_SIZE];
int top = -1 ;
void push(int n)
{
if(top>=50)
{
printf("STACK OVERFLOW\n");
}
else
ar[++top] = n ;
}
void pop()
{
if(top==-1)
{
printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
}
else
printf("%d\n",ar[top--]);
}

void Top()
{
if(top==-1)
{
printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
}
else
printf("%d\n",top);
}
int main()
{
int t ,tt, n , i , j , k ;
scanf("%d",&t);
while(t--)
{
scanf("%d",&tt);
while(tt--)
{
char s[100];
scanf("%s",&s);
if(strcmp(s,"PUSH")==0)
{
scanf("%d",&n);
push(n);
}
else if(strcmp(s,"POP")==0)
{
pop();
}
else if(strcmp(s,"TOP")==0)
{
Top();
}
}
top = -1 ;
}
return 0 ;
}
```

when i input

```
2
3
PUSH 1
PUSH 2
TOP
4
PUSH 1
POP
POP
TOP
```

and my expected output of the question is

```
1
2
2
1
1
STACK UNDERFLOW 
STACK UNDERFLOW
```

but instead my code is showing me this output

```
1
1
STACK UNDERFLOW
STACK UNDERFLOW
```

this is the problem pls help!!

Comment: Post your code what you did?

Comment: _"can someone pls give me the program for this Integer Stack"_. I would say **no, absolutely**. For you own good (because if you don't do your homework then they're meaningless and you won't learn anything) and for us (because we're not here to do your homework instead of you).

Comment: Dear sir, sorry iddidnt add it b4.it is showing me a different output .not my expecte output

Comment: what does it output and what do you expect? also please indent the code.

Comment: when i input                                                                                                        2
3
PUSH 1
PUSH 2
TOP
4
PUSH 1
POP
POP
TOP                                                                                                                                i need the output as                                                                                          1
2
2
1
1
STACK UNDERFLOW 
STACK UNDERFLOW                                                                                                but my codes output is coming1
1
STACK UNDERFLOW
STACK UNDERFLOW

Comment: 1) `if(top>=50)` --> `if(top>=49)`

Comment: tried dat @BLUEPIXY still not showing the expected output

Comment: nope not getting the correct answer

Comment: the thing is dat i have to get the output i mentioned only...nothinng else i think its a mistake in my code only

Comment: **PUSH operation print either the integer** 2)You do not have the display of numbers pushed a function of the push.

Comment: **TOP command print the top element** 3)You are displaying index rather than the elements.

Answer (score 0):

You can enhance your prog like this:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#define MAX_SIZE 50
int ar[MAX_SIZE];
int top = -1 ;

void push(int n)
{
    if(top>=50)
    {
        printf("STACK OVERFLOW\n");
    }
    else
    {
        top++;
        ar[top] = n ;
    }
}

void pop()
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
    printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("%d\n",ar[top]);
    top--;
    }
}

void Top()
{
    if(top==-1)
    {
    printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    }
    else
    {
    printf("%d\n",top);
    }
}

int display ( void )
{
    int choice;
    if ( top == -1 )
    {
        printf ( "\n Enter 1 for PUSH \n ");
        printf ( "\n Enter 3 for TOP value \n ");
        printf ( "\n Enter 0 to EXIT \n ");
        scanf ( "%d",&choice );
        if ( choice == 0 )
        {
            printf ( "\n Exited \n");
            exit ( 0 );
        }
    }
    else
    {
        printf ( "\n  Enter 1 for PUSH \n ");
        printf ( "\n Enter 2 for POP value \n ");
        printf ( "\n Enter 3 for TOP value \n ");
        printf ( "\n Enter 0 to EXIT \n ");
        scanf ( "%d",&choice );
        if ( choice == 0 )
        {
            printf ( "\n Exited \n");
            exit ( 0 );
        }
    }
    return ( choice );
}
int main()
{
    int choice, value;
    while ( 1 )
    {

    choice = display ( );

    switch ( choice )
    {
        case 1:
        printf ( "\n enter the value \n ");
        scanf ( "%d", &value );
        push ( value );
        break;

        case 2:
        pop ();
        break;

        case 3:
        Top ();
        break;

        default:
        printf ( "\n Wrong choice \n ");
        break;
    }

    }

    return 0 ;
}
```

Comment: i could have done that before also . but the problem is dat its a online submission portal. so it compiles online and in this case i am sure it wont compile after the menu screen. so it has to be a direct input output code.i would really appreciate if u would kindly have a look at my code and correct or give me corrections.

Answer (score 0):

Sample to fix.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h> //for strcmp

#define MAX_SIZE 50

int ar[MAX_SIZE];
int top = -1 ;

void push(int n){
    if(top>=MAX_SIZE-1){//49 is full
        printf("STACK OVERFLOW\n");
    }else{
        ar[++top] = n ;
        printf("%d\n", n);//display push value
    }
}
void pop(void){
    if(top==-1){
        printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    } else{
        printf("%d\n",ar[top--]);
    }
}
void Top(void){
    if(top==-1){
        printf("STACK UNDERFLOW\n");
    } else {
        printf("%d\n",ar[top]);//display element
    }
}
int main(void){
    int t ,tt, n;// , i , j , k ;<-unused

    scanf("%d",&t);
    while(t--){
        scanf("%d",&tt);
        while(tt--){
            char s[100];
            scanf("%99s", s);//&s --> s, 99 is safety for buffer overflow
            if(strcmp(s,"PUSH")==0){
                scanf("%d",&n);
                push(n);
            } else if(strcmp(s,"POP")==0){
                pop();
            } else if(strcmp(s,"TOP")==0){
                Top();
            }
        }
        top = -1;//reset
    }
    return 0 ;
}
```